# How to sum up negative and positive numbers in a list based on the row they occur

Tags: python, list, sum, sign

This is my original list:

```
list1 = [1,2,5,-2,-3,5,6,-3,0,-2,1,0,2]
```

I need to create a list of sum-up positive and negative as below:

```
list2 = [8,-5,11,-5,3]
```

Comment: So zero is considered both negative and positive for this purpose?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: What have you tried? This doesn't sound too difficult.

Comment: I'm baffled as to what's being asked. All the numbers are on the same row. As for where `list2` comes from, I have no idea.

Comment: @Acccumulation OP seems to mean *groups*: `[[1,2,5], [-2,-3], [5,6], [-3,0,-2], [1,0,2]]`

Comment: @Acccumulation Apparently "row" as in "it rained five days in a row".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with comment lines.

```
list1 = [1,2,5,-2,-3,5,6,-3,0,-2,1,0,2]

list2 = []

temp = 0
lastPositive = False

for i in list1: #Iterate through the list
    if (i == 0): #If i is zero, continue
        continue
    if ((i > 0) == (1 if lastPositive else 0)): #if last element is positive and now is positive, add i to temp
        temp += i
    else: #if not, the positivity changes and add temp to list2
        lastPositive = not lastPositive #Change the last positivity
        list2.append(temp) if temp != 0 else print()
        temp = i #Set temp to i for the rest of the list

list2.append(temp)
print(list2) #Then print the list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out zero elements, then use [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the same-signed items together, and then sum those.

```py
from itertools import groupby

def group_by_sign(values):
    nonzero = filter(None, values)  # filters out falsey values
    is_positive = lambda x: x > 0
    return [sum(group) for key, group in groupby(nonzero, is_positive)]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> values = [1, 2, 5, -2, -3, 5, 6, -3, 0, -2, 1, 0, 2]
>>> print(group_by_sign(values))
[8, -5, 11, -5, 3]
```

Comment: Beside the point, but [avoid named lambdas](/q/38381556/4518341). I would just put it inline here since it's so simple and only used once.

Comment: @wjandrea you are correct, and the Python PEP agrees with you, but I respectfully disagree with it. I want the benefit of self-documentation from naming it, without drawing unnecessary attention to that line by adding an indentation level. Yes, lambda exist to be be anonymous functions, but they have an implicit association with being "throw away" functions, and I wish to preserve that association.

Answer (score 1):

Keep summing, append/reset at sign changes.

```
list2 = []
s = 0
for x in list1:
    if s * x < 0:
        list2.append(s)
        s = 0
    s += x
if s:
    list2.append(s)
```